# Get the content of a tag with beautiful soup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have this html:

```
<a href="/watch?gl=US&amp;client=mv-google&amp;hl=en&amp;v=0C_yXOhJxWg">Miss Black OCU 2011</a>
```

My program reads a html file, and above is the chunk of that file. How do I extract "Miss Black OCU 2011" using BeautifulSoup in python.

Comment: do not use volatile services like pastebin!

Comment: And what is the particular criteria for your search???

Comment: you need to move the code from pastebin to your question. Your question will be around for years, but in 30 days it will lack all context whatsoever.

Comment: @pynator @Tim, stackoverflow didnt allow me to post here, thats why I switch their. I removing it

Answer (score 3):

Here's a quick fix:

```
>>> from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup as BS
>>> soup = BS('<a href="/watch?gl=US&amp;client=mv-google&amp;hl=en&amp;v=0C_yXOhJxWg">Miss Black OCU 2011</a>')
>>> tags = soup.findAll('a', href=True)
>>> for tag in tags: tag.renderContents() 
'Miss Black OCU 2011'
>>>
```